# Need slide out buttons to work separately. When one button is clicked both do the task.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have two buttons that I want when one is clicked that it slides out to show more information. When one button is clicked both slide out. I changed the second button classes to button2 and inner2 and doubled the javascript and changed classes in that to button2 and inner2 but that really made things get weird.

```
<a class="text button1 btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more<a class="link inner is-hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Movie Data</a><a class="link inner is-hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Full Trailer</a><a class="link inner is-hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#"More Reviews</a><a class="link inner is-hidden btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Photos</a></a>
```

---

```
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
animateDiv();
})

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 27 && $('.inner').hasClass('visible')) {
animateDiv();
}
})

function animateDiv() {
$('.inner').toggleClass('visible');
$('.inner').animate({
width: 'toggle',
}, 0);
}
```

Comment: I think your HTML seems incomplete or incorrectly formatted. Also, you're missing the CSS. Could you please create a JSbin that replicates what you currently have, and try and outline what the problem is, and what you're expecting? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `animateDiv`, you're referring to `.inner` which will match both buttons, or at least is going to match every element with that class. Unless you somehow specify which outer button it's referring to, it won't work.

Try passing the button into your function, and then scoping it:

```
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
  animateDiv($(this));
})

function animateDiv(button) {
  $('.inner', button).toggleClass('visible');
  $('.inner', button).animate({
    width: 'toggle',
  }, 0);
}
```

You'll still have an issue with your other bit of code, however, because there's no way that it could know which button you're referring to on a keyup for the whole document. The only way of not having it do both is to scope the keyup to the button too:

```
$('.button1').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27 && $('.inner', $(this)).hasClass('visible')) {
    animateDiv($(this));
  }
})
```

#### Edit:

Actually, I thought your HTML was formatted differently. It looks odd. Is there even a button2? Why are there so many `.inner`s inside `.button1`?

I thought at first that you had several cases of `.inner` divs inside of `.button123` divs. Difficult to tell when it's all on one line. But now wondering if your HTML is mangled or there's something missing in your question?